What is the correct way to link to the internal pages of static built application?
What is the accepted way to link to an internal page of a Static Built, Single Page Application (SPA), from outside the application.
Lets say you have a Next.js static build hosted at example.com/path/index.html
Currently there is a .htaccess file that rewrites /path/* to /path/index.html
Links in the SPA from react router look like example.com/path/internal/page
example:
// example.com/path/login
<Link to={`${this.settings.getClientBaseUrl()}login`}>


// /path/login
// The url in the browser looks like example.com/path/login
<Route exact path={`${this.settings.getClientBasePath()}login`} element={<LoginForm parent={this.parent} />} />

However /path/internal/page is not an actual file on the server only /path/index.html
What is the correct way to link directly to example.com/path/internal/page?

Does this answer your question? Apache settings for SPA using HTML5 History routing

You have to redirect the request and let React handle it.

This worked:
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>

